# how redux works here, i am going through a code base and did not understand how the function under another function dispaches

Tags: reactjs, redux

as you can see in my code when i call a function delete card it returns dispatch function then how does the remove card get called or worked in this case, thanks in advance

```
 export function deleteCard(data, callback) {
      return dispatch => {
        dispatch({type: DELETE_PAYMENT_CARD_REQUEST})
        return removeCard(data).then(res => {
          console.log("Remove card success.........", res);
          dispatch({type: DELETE_PAYMENT_CARD_SUCCESS, payload: res})
          if (callback) {
            callback({status: true, data: res})
          }
        }).catch(err => {
          dispatch({type: DELETE_PAYMENT_CARD_FAILURE, payload: err})
          if (callback) {
            callback({status: false, data: err})
          }
        });
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not that complicated. You need to make something like this:

```js
import store from 'store';

// Here we get this nested function which can be used later.
// Let's initialize it with the payment card data and the callback function.

const deleteCardResolver = deleteCard(
  { /*...your payment card data...*/ },
  (result) => {
    // This is the callback function that is called when success or failure occurs.
    // You can do something with result object. It has `status` and `data` fields as seen in question
  }
);
// Then you must get dispatch function from somewhere and pass it to deleteCardResolver.
// In this case we're going to use dispatcher from the store object.
// But, for example, you can also use `this.props.dispatch` if everything happens in a React component.

deleteCardResolver(store.dispatch);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply andrey i am not getting the code i have written as i am returning a dispatch in function and written another function inside that dispatch then how did the another dispatcher returns without calling it

Comment: See, (1) ```deleteCard()``` returns function, (2) then you pass a ```dispatch``` to that function (3) and then it returns ```Promise``` which is shown in the question. But if I get it right, you don't need to use that ```Promise``` object at all, because success or failure can be handled in your callback that you've passed in (1).

Comment: Callback also receives an object with fields (1) ```status```, which is ```true``` or ```false```, and (2) ```payload``` which is obviously the API response.